# how to show video with signed url of s3 object in open edx?

Tags: video, amazon-s3, openedx

I have the open edx plateform where I am using the s3 videos for displaying the lectures.
I need to display s3 videos with signed url I am very new to the open edx plateform.
The I am not able find where should I make the changes.
I have found the video_module but I am not getting what to change and how 
I know the solution will be big so can you please so me the path where can I work upon it.

Thank you